# Maximum number of Individuals in Protege OWL file

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

Just like Data bases have a restriction on number of rows etc I was wondering is there limit on number of individuals in Ontology file (OWL) in Protege 4? i have dictionary resource having more than 50,000 entries. But recently i have introduced machine learning in it that will make the numbers of individuals in OWL grow. So i wanted to ask will it have any detrimental effect?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on the Protege mailing list.  Have you actually run into a problem with too many individuals, yet?  I'd expect (but don't know) that Protege can probably handle a very large number of individuals, but that it's reasoners that might have more of a problem.  (But even so, many reasoners can probably handle lots of individuals, too.)  There are really too many factors to give a good answer about this.

Comment: Have you discovered the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

> Protégé is quite capable of handling 1,000,000 individuals, but certain OWL constructs can introduce problems. Another question is whether you intend to use a reasoner. If you do you’ll want to be careful what kind, and how many, class restrictions you introduce into your ontology.

Source: http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Maximum-Number-of-Instances-in-Protege-and-Other-Ontology-Editors-td4656564.html